# python Django repeat url many times

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-urls

I'm a starter of Django1.10. I just started play around with it. I am trying to show an image on website.

This is myproject/settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')  
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

and myproject/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import  static
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^poster/', include('poster.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls ),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

myproject/app/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Info
# give a set of summary of items
def index(request):
    latest_item_list = Info.objects.all()
    context = {'latest_item_list': latest_item_list}
    return render(request, 'poster/index.html', context)
def detail(request, item_id):

    return HttpResponse("This function will return detail info for items %s" % item_id)
```

myproject/app/models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Info(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.info_text
    info_text = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    info_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y%m/%d')
```

myproject/app/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # ex:/poster
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /poster/5
    url(r'^(?P<item_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name = 'detail'),
]
```

myproject/app/templates/app/index.html

```
{% if latest_item_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for item in latest_item_list %}
       {{forloop.counter}}.<a href="{{ item.info_image.url }}/">{{ item.info_text }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No poster are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

If I run python manage.py runserver, and go http://127.0.0.1:8000/poster/. I can see one object I created before, when I click it, the url it points to get repeated many times
[image]

I believe there is something wrong in the url.py, but I am not sure. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I think you are missing a forwardshals in your `models.py` on line :

```
info_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y%m/%d')
```

Unless it's your intention, I think it should be like this:

```
info_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d')
                                                   ^
```

Next thing is that you are not providing the right url for `href` attribute in the `<a>` tag of your `index.html` template.

```
{{forloop.counter}}.<a href="{{ item.info_image.url }}/">{{ item.info_text }}</a>
```

This line will point to the image itself. So you can use it example in the `<image src="{{ item.info_image.url }}" />` but not in a link tag. So I guess this is what you were looking for.

To point to your `detail` view of specific image you would want to ideally create `get_absolute_url` method on your `Info` model class.

> [**Model.get_absolute_url()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url)
>
> Define a get_absolute_url() method to tell Django how to calculate the canonical URL for an object. To callers, this method should appear to return a string that can be used to refer to the object over HTTP.

For example:

```
# models.py
class Info(models.Model):
    ...
    info_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y%m/%d')
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('detail',
                       args=[self.id])
```

Then you could use that in your template like this:

```
{{forloop.counter}}.<a href="{{ item.get_absolute_url }}">{{ item.info_text }}</a>
```

and display your image, wherever you want, using:

```
<image src="{{ item.info_image.url }}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked how the URL looks in the generated HTML code? E.g. does the URL look correct when the HTML is loaded, and when you click it, it starts repeating it?

Comment: The HTML works fine, I tried manually type in the value of item.info_image.url. As long as it hits this url, the url start repeating.

Comment: Can you post the URL you have in the HTML?

Comment: If i look at your comment in the urls.py it says
 `# ex: /poster/5
    url(r'^(?P<item_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name = 'detail'),`
to achieve what is in the comment it would have to look like (notice the / infront)
`url(r'^/(?P<item_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name = 'detail'),`
Though from the URL it looks like your URL needs something like
`url(r'^/images/$', views.detail, name = 'detail'),`
to be able to relate images. 
Though i would recommend you to store the images with an ID of a kind in the model, so you can use `{% url 'detail' question.id %}` notation to create URLs.

Comment: Have to run now, but have a look at the Django "Writing your first Django app". It is quite a good tutorial to learn Django. Below link to where they explain urls.py and views.py.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial03/